# How to add a new line to HTML text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this code which essentially types text onto the screen. I am unsure how to add a new line to the string which is being displayed.

I have already tried \n for those posting their answers. This does NOT work. A new line is not started in my HTML

Code:

```js
var myString = "public class MyResume implements Resume{" +
    /*this is where I want the new line*/ "...." ;

var myArray = myString.split("");
var loopTimer;
function frameLooper() {
  if(myArray.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += myArray.shift();
  } else {
    clearTimeout(loopTimer); 
    return false;
  }
  loopTimer = setTimeout('frameLooper()',70);
}
frameLooper();
```

```html
<div id="myTypingText"></div>
```

Comment: var myString = 'public class MyResume implements Resume{\n'+

Comment: I tried that already. It doesn't start a new line, but the '\n' does not appear in the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an overly simplistic approach with full code.  Use a tilde ~ and then watch for it in your frameLooper to insert a 
 like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="myTypingText"></div>
<script>
var myString = 'public class MyResume implements Resume{~....' ;

var myArray = myString.split("");
var loopTimer;
function frameLooper() {
if(myArray.length > 0) {
    var char = myArray.shift();
        if (char === '~')
    { document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += '<br/>'; }
    else
    { document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += char; }
} else {
    clearTimeout(loopTimer); 
            return false;
}
loopTimer = setTimeout('frameLooper()',70);
}
frameLooper();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `<br>`.Just like`"your string.<br> new line"`

Comment: This doesn't work either. The HTML isn't being recognized. It just displays "<br>" on the screen

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding `<br>` to `myString` doesn't work because you're inserting each character at one time. When a character gets added with `innerHTML`, JavaScript encodes it:

```
$('element').innerHTML += "<";
> "string&lt;"
```

If you did this for each character in `<br>`, you'd end up with

```
>"string&lt;br&lt;"
```

You need some way to tell your script to add the entire element when you reach a "break character". You could use an uncommon character like a pipe `|` or you could add a method which looks ahead to make sure that the next few characters don't spell out `<br>`.

Comment: Yeah, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks. Since it's splitting each character into an array, how would I be able to find the break statement? Or is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Use an uncommon character or teach your script to look ahead.

Comment: Can I add the uncommon character and then split the string based on that character. Then I could individually split each substring within its own characters?

Answer (score 1):

To add string to a new line, you need the `\n` in your string. For example:

```
var string = 'This is the first line \nThis is the second line'

console.log(string)
```

This would output

```
This is the first line 
This is the second line
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. It doesn't start a new line, but the '\n' does not appear in the text

Comment: I know how to start a new line, its just that it isn't working in my HTML

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just append ul>li or p to your text, something like this:

```
document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += "<p>" + myArray.shift() "</p>";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += "<li>" + myArray.shift() "</li>";
```

with:

```
<ul id="myTypingText"></ul>
```

Comment: This just adds each character to a new paragraph lol. I want to format the string to look like an actual java program.